# Mounting Database in SQL Server 2005 (not Express) without Control Panel access

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to upload a database into my webhost's server. It has got support for SQL Server 2005 only, **no SQL Server Express** plus ASP.NET 3.5. The webhost neither provided a control panel access nor any login access to Management Studio for uploading the database.

If they supported SQL Server 2005 Express, I can dynamically attach the database using C# code with proper connection string.

But I would like to ask here, if there is any way I could attach the database to SQL Server dynamically or any other way possible?

Hope someone can understand my problem...

Thank you!

Comment: So what *do* they supply you with for your SQL Server facility? You must have some kind of access or information

Comment: Nope, sadly, got only ftp login information :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that "attach a .MDF from disk" feature is available in the **Express** editions only, and there's no way (not even when hell freezes over) to do this in a "full-blown" SQL Server installation.

You will need to either get the necessary access (to SQL Server Mgmt Studio) from your web hoster, or choose something like [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://robtiffany.com/sql-server-compact/here-comes-sql-server-compact-4-0) which is just a .sdf file to copy to a drive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information you provided...I'll try something else...